# Comparing associative arrays inside foreach loop laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

Using eloquent, I am querying two sets of data like so:

```
$all_perms = Permission::all(); //all permissions
$role_perms = Auth::user()->roles()->permissions; //permissions belonging to a role
```

`$role_perms` is a subset of `$all_perms` and what I want is to loop both arrays and come out with a new array containing all permissions already assigned to a role together with those not yet assigned to a role.

What I have done is loop through both arrays in a foreach loop and if any one array belongs to both sets, I mark it by adding a `check` key with corresponding value 1 to the array so that I can identify is as a permission already assigned to a role.

```
foreach ($role_perms as $role_perm) {
    foreach ($all_perms as $key => $value ) {
        if (array_diff_assoc($all_perm, $role_perm)) {
            $all_perm['check'] = 1; 
        }
    }
}
```

but it keeps throwing the error:

> array_diff_assoc(): Argument #1 is not an array

Are they better ways of doing this? Or what can I do on this one to make it work?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

That's because it's a collection, not an array. If you want to get an array, try to use `toArray()`:

```
$all_perms = Permission::all()->toArray();
```

Also, is this a typo here:

```
array_diff_assoc($all_perm, $role_perm);
```

It should be `$all_perms`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the wonderful contains method that is available on all your collections:

```
foreach ($role_perms as $role_perm) {
   if($all_perms->contains($role_perm))
   {
      // do whatever is needed
   }
}
```

Checkout the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-contains) for help with the contains method.